# Extracting index of minimum point in 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, minimum

I'm testing values of A and B in a function and need to find the mimum value of that function and what values of A and B produce this minimum. I'm struggling to find a way to get these values out of the array I have made.

I start by defining some arrays

```
ones = np.ones((3456,5184))
array = np.zeros([5,5])
real = threshold
test = testsunthree
```

Where real and test are arrays defined early in the code.

```
for A in range(-2,2):
  for B in range(-2,2):
    array[A,B]=((np.mean((real-(test*(A*0.1)+((B*0.1)*ones))**2))))
```

Here I am testing values of A and B over the range between -2 and 2 and for each value plugging them into the function. The value of that function is then stored in the empty array defined above.

```
array_min = array[array != 0].min()
print (array_min)
print zip(*np.where(array == array.min()))
```

I am then trying to identify the minimum value of that array and want to find for what values of A and B is this function at its minimum. This is the part I am struggling with as the last two lines are giving incorrect values.

Comment: Can you copy paste the whole code ? "threshold" isn't defined and numpy isn't imported, it would be easier for us to work on your code.

Comment: threshold is actually an array of an image of the sun so I'm not able to import that image on here, the size of the array is (3456, 5184)

Answer (score 0):

This is giving you the minimum value of the array called `array`. I put random values for `threshold` and `testsunthree` to make the code work and change the utilisation of the `min()` function

```
import numpy as np

threshold = 4
testsunthree = 2
ones = np.ones((3456,5184))
array = np.zeros([5,5])
real = threshold
test = testsunthree

for A in range(-2,2):
  for B in range(-2,2):
     array[A,B]=((np.mean((real-(test*(A*0.1)+((B*0.1)*ones))**2))))

array_min = np.min(array)
print (array_min)
```

I quickly made a dirty solution to obtain the different A,B values for which you have the min value of your array, it can be improved easily as it's only a quick fix to show you the way

```
index = np.where(array == array_min)
A_B_value = []

for i in range(0, len(index[0])):
    min_index = []
    min_index.append(index[0][i])
    min_index.append(index[1][i])
    A_B_value.append(min_index)

print(A_B_value)
```

Comment: How would I then get the values of A and B which give this minimum?